# Dragging down formula until the last filled cell with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to automatize the following step:

I want the formula dragging down from the last filled cell of column G that contains a vlookup formula.

Since the excel file is dynamic it is important to be dragged down until the only the last filled cell of column F.

Please see the attached picture.

[image]

Comment: Just add the formula in G2 and use FillDown.

Comment: If you have no idea how to write the code start using the macro recorder while doing the steps manually. This gives you a first idea. But make sure you read and apply [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) right after using the macro recorder. • Also you will find many tutorials on how to determine the last used cell in column F.

Comment: Possible duplicate of the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488162/macro-to-auto-fill-down-to-last-adjacent-cell?rq=1